# How to access data from an imported component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I have a `navbar.component.ts` which has `(click)=toggle(!isOn);` which changes the value of `ison` to `true` or `false` .

I have another component `welcome.component.ts`. I imported `navbar.component.ts` as `Navbar`. When I try to log `Navbar.isOn` it says `undefined`. when I log `Navbar` it gives

```
function Navbar() {
    this.selectedcity = 'Location';
    this.isOn = false;
    this.isDisabled = false;
}
```

How to access the value of `isOn`. What I want to do is make the overflow of body hidden when the user clicks the button.

Angular 2 Version 2.0.0-beta.15

Comment: please upgrade your version of Angular

Comment: The code is already far made. How difficult would be it to change the whole code to the final version of angular. Also, will Navbar.isOn give a result in the new version?

Comment: Do you have any relation between these two components?

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE : Other ways are also there but need to know relation bet components.***

use (as of now) **Injector** as shown below,

```
import {App} from 'src/app';

constructor(private inj:Injector){}
click(){
         let parentComponent = this.inj.get(App);
         console.log(parentComponent.isOn)
         this.val=parentComponent.isOn;   //<----other component property

}
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/xYO7zA?p=preview**